# Holy Cow, I won at Answerama -- what now?

Tags: support, site-promotion, answerama

I just noticed by coincidence that I won at Answerama (and promptly checked my SE mail account to find a nice mail from Brett). Can I influence the prize I get?

I noticed that [Futurama Season "6"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005QIOJUI) is a lot cheaper than the items that are listed as actual prizes. Since I have no huge use for the actual prizes I would prefer to get that. So to keep this question general; Would something like that be possible?

If not; Can I somehow choose from the listed prizes? For example; I'd prefer a Farnsworth or Zoidberg Toynami figurine, over a, say, monopoly game. Any chance there?

Comment: I think the rules are pretty clear.

Comment: @Keen: Quote the relevant part then, please. It says the prizes are ultimately chosen by StackExchange, but nothing about whether you can indicate preference or not.

Comment: "Daily winners will receive up to 2 of the options listed below, *as chosen by Stack Exchange*"  You'll note that your email from Brett didn't ask which prize you wanted.

Comment: Posting as a comment since in the grand tradition of SFF this was summarily closed with no feedback from the community: `You can ask but no likelyhood of positive result. Specifically; Brett and other SE liasons are extremely well-natured, polite and helpful; and **will** hear you out and respond; and if possible WILL accommodate you. **However**, they are frequently limited by either legal constraints, accounting/logistical constraints; or rules imposed by non-SE partner. Ergo, you should always assume that the answer will be a well-explained 'No'. I had experiened both types of answers.`

Comment: @Keen - the wording doesn't say what the process of choosing is. Personally, I'd prefer an answer from Brett or someone else from SE than your (possibly well reasoned and likely correct, yet not necessarily authoritative) opinion.

Comment: Brett concurred with me that this should be left closed.

Answer (score 2):

I hope not, because everyone who has had their prize already sent out may feel slightly hard done by at not having the same opportunity. :)

That said, the Answerama site is pretty unambiguous at saying the prize(s) will be selected by SE, i.e. not open for personal selection.

Comment: Sure, its a legal thing to say that, so you don't have the *right* to claim a certain prize. I'm just kindly asking, if Brett would be nice enough to consider taking my request into account when choosing the prize. I mean, if it's all the same to the power that be, why choose something I would like less over something I'd rather have?